# What are N and D variables which take part in this Gibbs' method/algorithm for orbit determination

Tags: orbit-determination

I am trying to make sense of [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/gibbs-method) algorithm, which is the Gibbs method of orbit determination from three position vectors. More specifically, I am trying to understand the equations 5.13 and 5.14.

> 5.13: $N = {r_1}{r_2} × {r_3} + {r_2}{r_3} × {r_1} + {r_3}{r_1} × {r_2}$
>
> 5.14: $D={r_1} × {r_2} + {r_2} × {r_3} + {r_3} × {r_1}$

What are they? Why are they needed and what do they calculate?

Answer (score 2):

From the page you linked, it looks like N and D are just intermediate values used to make the following equations shorter and more readable.

Comment: I thought of that too, but it's odd nomenclature for that usage.

Comment: I agree. There are several variables in that derivation that use nomenclature I'd consider odd, but over half the alphabet is used in the derivation. After a point I suppose it gets hard to meaningfully name each variable with a single letter. For example, N, D, h, and w are all vectors which are normal to the orbital plane.

Answer (score 1):

Look at equation 5-16, which says $h^2$ (the squared magnitude of the specific angular momentum, which is the quantity you wish to know) equals $\mu$ (the gravitational parameter $GM$ for the body being orbited) times the magnitude of $N$ divided by the magnitude of $D$.  Therefore, $N$ means **numerator** and $D$ means **denominator**.